# JMeter - view more results in View Results Tree

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

In JMeter GUI when I check execution issues over time I'm using `View Results Tree`

When I want to stop and view an issue I can see only ~4000 request,

It seems that there's a maximum of requests that is display in GUI,

Can number of request in GUI be increased (or just show all)?

Also when test in running It's causing my problematic request to move up even if `Scroll automatically?` is unchecked

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In jmeter.properties [view.results.tree.max_results](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) property control the number

Set it to 0 for unlimited results.

> # Maximum number of results in the results tree
>
> # Set to 0 to store all results (might consume a lot of memory)

```
view.results.tree.max_results=0
```

**Edit** updated in [JMeter docs](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

> Starting with version 3.2 the number of entries in the View is restricted to the value of the property view.results.tree.max_results which defaults to 500 entries. The old behaviour can be restored by setting the property to 0. Beware, that this might consume a lot of memory.