# How can I display the full content logged by a sampler in View Results Tree -> Response Data -> Response Body?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jsr223

In JMeter, I am using a JSR223 Sampler with some code to send messages to an IBM MQ and logging this message to the sample result in this way:

```
SampleResult.setResponseData(msg.toString())
```

[image]

Then I am using the View Results Tree -> Response Data -> Response Body to see what was sent.

[image]

The problem is that in View Results Tree -> Response Data -> Response Body, I don't see all the content of the message sent. There seems to be some maximum characters limitations, because I am seeing only a part of the sent message and then there is an ellipses (`...`) sign shown.

How can I display the full length of the sent message ?

UPDATE:
I am not interested in the maximum number or sample results which can be shown inside the view results tree; I am interested in the maximum content (aka character limits which can be seen in the screenshot above) which can be displayed inside one sampler.

Comment: You can disable the size check with `view.results.tree.max_size=0`. Add the property into the user.properties file->save the file and restart JMeter. Please refer to (Properties Reference)[https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html] for more details.

Comment: @Janesh Kodikara Thanks, after my post got closed with a reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694560/jmeter-view-more-results-in-view-results-tree), I found this option too and have set it, but it made no difference. Then  started to print variables from the script in the screenshots to see what is happening. It seems that log.info(payload) is printing the full string message content but `msg` variable is of type com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage and if I print this out as string it does indeed end up as sample result shows in the screenshot with ellipses (`...`) at the end

Comment: @JaneshKodikara The above answer you gave me is the correct one, but after more investigation, I found that it was not my problem. The problem was my expectation of the  functionality of the toString() method. The method was functioning correctly as per the documentation, I just didn't know how to interpret it. [Link to post which cleared it out for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69790388/why-does-a-variable-of-type-com-ibm-jms-jmstextmessage-print-truncated-content-a.)