# Why does a variable of type com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage print truncated content and ellipses (...)?

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, jms, ibm-mq

I would like to understand why a variable of type com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage is printed with truncated content and ellipses (...) when converted to string.

I have this code in a JSR223 Sampler in JMeter:

```
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants
import javax.jms.Session
import javax.jms.TextMessage

def hostName = "127.0.0.1"
def hostPort = 1414
def channelName = "DEV.APP.SVRCONN"
def queueManagerName = "QM1"
def queueName = "DEV.QUEUE.1"

def ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER)
def cf = ff.createConnectionFactory()

cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostName)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, hostPort)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channelName)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT)

def connInboundQueue = cf.createConnection("user", "password")

def sessInboundQueue = connInboundQueue.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)


def payload = "AAA:+.? '\n" +
        "ABC+ABCD:1+ABCDEFG:ZZ+ABCDEF:ZZ+123456:2042+12345678901++ABCD'\n" +
        "DEF+ABCD+LH+FVKJUB+20000:2042+Y1234567+UN+D:21B'\n" +
        "GHI+1+ABCD:D:11A:AA:ABCD+ABCD12345678901123ABC123456'\n" +
        "JKL+745'\n" +
        "HHH+TN:IIAA891011213531235BNM422244:::001'\n" +
        "CCC+NT+++ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS'\n" +
        "STU+00123456789012:UF+0000000000:GY'\n" +
        "VXY+50+MI1234+++MI'\n" +
        "AAA+235+ABC'\n" +
        "BBB+200:3202062000:301'\n" +
        "FFF+90+USA'\n" +
        "BBB+232:2101051135:201'\n" +
        "CCC+FF+++AaBaBa001:TEST1'\n" +
        "DDD+3++G'\n" +
        "EEE+329:711013'\n" +
        "FFF+178+XXX'\n" +
        "FFF+179+YYY'\n" +
        "GGG+2+ZZZ'\n" +
        "HHH+BXG:ABCDEF'\n" +
        "HHH+ABC:12AB3E01234E8UD8'\n" +
        "III+P:110:111+100000001'\n" +
        "EEE+36:281105'\n" +
        "FFF+91+ASD'\n" +
        "VVV+50:2'\n" +
        "XXX+0011+1'\n" +
        "YYY+1+U0123456'\n" +
        "ZZZ+1+U1234560002'\n"

TextMessage msg = sessInboundQueue.createTextMessage()
msg.setText(payload)

log.info(msg.toString())
log.info(msg.getClass().toString())
log.info(msg.getText())
```

I would like to understand why `log.info(msg.toString())` does not print the whole text content and show ellipses after some `point (...)`

If I do `log.info(msg.getText())`, I can see the whole text message.

Here is the print outcome in jmeter's console:

```
2021-10-31 22:05:25,491 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler - Producer - Inbound Queue: 
  JMSMessage class: jms_text
  JMSType:          null
  JMSDeliveryMode:  2
  JMSDeliveryDelay: 0
  JMSDeliveryTime:  1635710725481
  JMSExpiration:    0
  JMSPriority:      4
  JMSMessageID:     ID:414d5120514d312020202020202020201f537d6101c31040
  JMSTimestamp:     1635710725481
  JMSCorrelationID: 1757416553
  JMSDestination:   queue:///DEV.QUEUE.1
  JMSReplyTo:       null
  JMSRedelivered:   false
    JMSXAppID: 4.1\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar    
    JMSXDeliveryCount: 0
    JMSXUserID: mquser1     
    JMS_IBM_PutApplType: 28
    JMS_IBM_PutDate: 20211031
    JMS_IBM_PutTime: 20052548
AAA:+.? '
ABC+ABCD:1+ABCDEFG:ZZ+ABCDEF:ZZ+123456:2042+12345678901++ABCD'
DEF+ABCD+LH+FVKJUB+20000:20 ...
2021-10-31 22:05:25,491 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler - Producer - Inbound Queue: class com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage
2021-10-31 22:05:25,491 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler - Producer - Inbound Queue: AAA:+.? '
ABC+ABCD:1+ABCDEFG:ZZ+ABCDEF:ZZ+123456:2042+12345678901++ABCD'
DEF+ABCD+LH+FVKJUB+20000:2042+Y1234567+UN+D:21B'
GHI+1+ABCD:D:11A:AA:ABCD+ABCD12345678901123ABC123456'
JKL+745'
HHH+TN:IIAA891011213531235BNM422244:::001'
CCC+NT+++ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS'
STU+00123456789012:UF+0000000000:GY'
VXY+50+MI1234+++MI'
AAA+235+ABC'
BBB+200:3202062000:301'
FFF+90+USA'
BBB+232:2101051135:201'
CCC+FF+++AaBaBa001:TEST1'
DDD+3++G'
EEE+329:711013'
FFF+178+XXX'
FFF+179+YYY'
GGG+2+ZZZ'
HHH+BXG:ABCDEF'
HHH+ABC:12AB3E01234E8UD8'
III+P:110:111+100000001'
EEE+36:281105'
FFF+91+ASD'
VVV+50:2'
XXX+0011+1'
YYY+1+U0123456'
ZZZ+1+U1234560002'
```

Comment: Have you checked the source?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen What do you mean by source? I have checked this [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=jms-jmstextmessage)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I've added the imports now. Hopefully that's what you were referring to?

Comment: No, the source of the toString() method in question.

Comment: @JustNatural, why you have decided it should print full message?

Comment: @daggett I just thought that's what toString()'s supposed to do. Now I think I understand how to interpret the documentation and that my expectation is no guarantee. I really appreciated the explanation of Justin Bertram. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=jms-jmstextmessage) `com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage` inherits the `toString()` implementation from `com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage` and [the JavaDoc for that method](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/jms/JMSMessage.html#toString--) says:

> Gets a String containing a formatted version of the message header.

My guess is that the body is cut off simply because `toString()` is really just meant to give you the header. However, only IBM would know for sure why it works that way. To be clear, there is no guarantee that `toString()` will (or should) return the entire body of the message.

If you really want to inspect the body of the text message you should invoke `getText()`. This method is required to return the body of the text-message according to [the JMS JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/TextMessage.html#getText--) as well as [IBM's own JavaDoc](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/jms/JMSTextMessage.html#getText--). Both state:

> Gets the String containing this message's data. The default value is null.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it makes sense. Your answer really helped me understand how to read the documentation. I checked that link, but did not know how to interpret it cause I'm a noob. :) ; Also the fact that toString() does not guarantee the return of the entire body of the message (or that it should) was very insightful to me.